# URL's pasted in the Yammer embedFeed does not work

Tags: jquery, html, yammer

I am trying to use the Yammer commenting feed. The code I am using is below:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"></script>
<div id="embedded-feed" style="height:400px;width:500px;"></div>
<script>
    yam.connect.embedFeed({
        container: "#embedded-feed",
        network: "xyz.com.au",
        feedType: "open-graph",
        objectProperties: {
            url: "https://box.com/file/abc123",
            type: "page",
            title: "Yammer ROI.pdf"
        },
        config: {
            header: false,
            footer: false,
            promptText: "Comment on this news ... ",
            defaultGroupId: 12642178  // specify default news group id to post to
        }
    });
</script>
```

Whenever I try to comment something using this feed, the URL is not carried over to the default yammer group.

Could any one help me with this?

Comment: We are seeing the same problem this week.  It had been working correctly previously.